# how to override the get_ending_note() from HelpFormatter?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need help on overriding the get_ending_note() from HelpFormatter

As the help command is default in english, and my bot is meant to be in an Spanish server, i need to change the 
"type !help command for help on a command..." line at the end of the help message to one in spanish.

I know this is not discordAPI/discord.py specific but python, so It would be great if someone explained to me how to override a class on python applied to this specific scenario, becasue the tutorials that I have found googling have further confused me rather than help me understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a subclass of `HelpFormatter` and pass an instance of that subclass to `Bot`:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, HelpFormatter

class MyFormatter(HelpFormatter):
    def get_ending_note(self):
        return "This is the new ending note"

bot = Bot("!", formatter=MyFormatter())
```

Comment: My initial thoughts on overriding it were okay, but I didn't take into account the basic thing of: loading the HelpFormatter module into the code. Thanks, this worked

Comment: Oh, I need one clarification here. What is the initial "!" on the last line of code for?

Comment: That's the [`command_prefix`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command_prefix).  It's not really relevant here, but `Bot` requires it.